# Combine polygons from different sources

Tags: polygon, accuracy, historical-maps

I am currently working on a project where I try to reconstruct historical borders of the austro-hungarian empire between 1815 and 1918. Therfore I use the comination of digitized old maps an legal texts, as well as already existing shapefiles.

I would like to create a homogenous dataset and afterwords split it to the different time spans where administrative changes took place.

For some regions and timespans we use already existing shapefiles. E.g. from HGIS or Census Mosaic Project (https://censusmosaic.demog.berkeley.edu).

The problem is now that the polygons won't suit together. I fight with great inaccuracies, inconsistencies and data heterogenity. The files are mismatching and contraicting.

At the moment I revise the polygons manually, but I am looking for a way to adapt and harmonice the data more automatized. Creat differences are especially at the external borders, as you can see in the picture below.

Does anybody know a way how I can deal with this problem or a tool i could use to match the borders and the polygons?

I work with QGIS and do not have a lot of programming/Python skills though.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to have the same boundaries or just the best overlap between two layers, overlap found with some points, like raster georeferencing ?

Comment: If you are digitizing the map yourself and try to overlap it with another shapefile it will never be exact match. Your digitizing is subjective (some will use curve lines, some will use more vertices than others etc.) From what I understand out of your description, your only way out is manually matching one polygon to another.

Comment: QGIS has a tool called "Snap geometries to layer" that might help. You can pick one layer that you decide is "right" and snap the other layers to that. Or you can manually draw the borderline that seems like the best average, and snap all the layers to that.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I want to have the same boundaries. I have a good data set and I want to adapt the other data to this one... Thanks csk I will try the tool "Snap geometries to layer".

Comment: I also have another problem with the polygons, some of them have a lot of points others are very generalized. Are there any tolls methods to generalize them the same way or reduce points automatically? (sorry for my english)

Comment: One technique is to `Reshape features` ([doc here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#reshape-features)), extend your polygon over the other polygon boundaries, and after, you just need to clip it.